# vbscript with outdated MS Access and Outlook

Tags: email, ms-access, vbscript, outlook

I have a VBscript that I wrote for someone that access their Microsoft Access Database and sends an email, via Outlook, to people in the database if they fit a certain criteria. I have the script run every day via Task Manager. **The important part of the script is to run completely in the background**

I developed this script on Windows 7 with the 2013 version of Access and Outlook, but when I went to set up the code on the person's computer, they had an out-dated version of Microsoft Office (I'm pretty sure it's 2010 or 2007, but I'm not familiar with any Office products earlier than 2013). Everything worked fine on Windows 7 with Office 2013

When I ran the script I came across two errors:

1. Outlook prompted the user saying that a script is trying to automatically send an email and to allow it to do so.
2. The email wasn't went strait to the outbox and wouldn't send (although I'm pretty sure that's because I didn't set up the Outlook account right)

How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
Dim connStr, objConn, getNames 
connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\source\to\database.accdb" 
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
objConn.open connStr 
Set rs = objConn.execute("SELECT Fname, Email, VolunteerDate, ID, VolunteerTime FROM people") 
DO WHILE NOT rs.EOF 
getNames = getNames + rs.Fields(1) & "," 
Dim diff 
diff = DateDiff("d",Date,rs.Fields(2)) 

Select Case diff 
Case 0 
Call sendTodayEmail(rs.Fields(1),rs.Fields(2),rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(4)) 
Case 7  
Call sendWeekEmail(rs.Fields(1),rs.Fields(2),rs.Fields(0), rs.Fields(4)) 
Case else 
End Select 

rs.MoveNext 
Loop 

Sub sendTodayEmail(a,b,c,d) 
dim objOutlk 
dim objMail 
dim strMsg 
const olMailItem = 0 
set objOutlk = createobject("Outlook.Application") 
set objMail = objOutlk.createitem(olMailItem) 
objMail.To = a 
objMail.subject = "Automatic Email" 
strMsg = "Hello " & c & ", this is a reminder that you are scheduled to help today at " & d 
objMail.body = strMsg 
objMail.Send 
End Sub 

Sub sendWeekEmail(a,b,c,d) 
dim objOutlk 
dim objMail 
dim strMsg 
const olMailItem = 0 
set objOutlk = createobject("Outlook.Application") 
set objMail = objOutlk.createitem(olMailItem) 
objMail.To = a 
objMail.subject = "Automatic Email" 
strMsg =  "Hello " & c & ", this is a reminder that you are scheduled to help one week from today at "  & d & "." & vbCrLf & "Scheduled date: " & b & vbCrLf & "Scheduled time: " & d 
objMail.body = strMsg 
objMail.Send 
End Sub 

Set objConn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of Outlook will not display security prompts if an up-to-date version of an anti-virus app is installed.

Otherwise your options are either Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only), [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am its author) or products like ClickYes.

See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for more details.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what I could do with the Extended MAPI?

Comment: You would be able to call IMessage::SubmitMessage() without a security prompt.

Comment: I don't know C or C++ or Delphi so is there any way you could change your answer to include a code example?

Comment: That uses Extended MAPI? You can only access it from C++ or Delphi.

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example of C++ or Delphi? I don't know what I'm supposed to do with this

Comment: I am confused - what good would it do if you are not using C++ or Delphi?

Comment: well you're the one that suggested that I use C++ or Delphi

Comment: It is an option only if you are already using C++ or Delphi. Or if you are willing to rewrite your whole project in C++ or Delphi. Otherwise try Redemption or ClickYes.

Comment: thank you. that was the answer I was looking for. I'll mark you as best answer